# Use of a column in excel sheet as an input in update statement in Oracle using PL/SQL

Tags: database, excel, oracle, plsql

I'm just curious - is it possible to use the values in a column of an excel sheet sitting in my C:/ as an input in an update statement I'm writing in PL/SQL connected to an Oracle DB.
Update Statement:

```
update inventorylist
set Type = "Metals"
    Location = "Store A"
where Unique_ID IN (2234, 2455, 5578);
```

The Unique_ID values are in this particular column of the Excel file. So is it possible to pull the values from the file into the update statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt, there is a way to read the values directly from Excel into Oracle.  But that requires importing the data or connecting to Excel to read them.

I would just add a new column with a formula like:

```
=A1&", "
```

Copy that formula down.  Then copy the results into my query window for the `IN` list.  Remember to remove the last comma.

Comment: that's what I'm using but I'd like a scenario where I don't have to open or work with the excel file. Prefer a way for Oracle to pick the column contents from the Excel file once I specify the path of the Excel fie and use same in the update statement.

Comment: @BasilOgbunude . . . This is trickier than you might think.  The file is located on your *local* drive.  Oracle is (presumably) on a *remove* server.  You are logged in as  yourself locally.  The server is running (presumably) under a different user id.  Just to get started, you need to find a network location accessible to both you and the server and give the file permissions so you can read and write the file and Oracle can at least read the file.